# Is there any way to create colors for special tags?

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-highlighting

Over at cstheory, we have a set of "recommended tags" loosely based off of the Arxiv.org classification for subfields of theoretical computer science, and we recommend that each question have at least one of these tags. However, there's no way to distinguish these tags from others by color (for example) and we are currently debating whether we should rename these tags to mark them as "special" in some way.

But colorizing would be a far better option, since we just need some visual indicator of category. My question is:

> Is there any hope that we could get
>   tag colors ?